# How to calculate this capacitor value?

Tags: transformer, driver, mosfet-driver, pulse, gate-driving

How to calculate this capacitor on pulse transformer primary?
[image]

I've tried 470 nF but the PWM on capacitor's output lost its level, normally both PWM are 0 to 12V, but when I put this cap, the PWM on cap's output becomes -5V to 7V (even when I disconnect the transformer). I don't know that's wrong with it. Frequency is 30 kHz.

Comment: Why should that be a problem?

Comment: The transformer starts to drain lots of current like 2.5A, actually I can't find the problem on circuit but I'm not sure if this voltage level change is normal or not.

Comment: Why are you replacing the capacitor? Faulty component? How do you know the "normal" voltage range?

Comment: Are the transformers getting saturated or is 2.5 A just the normal magnetization current?